# Archiving File on Client's Computer

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

my problem is that I need to find a way to archive a file uploaded by the **client** and placed into a folder onto the **client’s** machine using a web app created in C# asp.net.  Currently the web app has the upload feature in use that sends the file to a server and clients manually archive the file, so no work is necessary on uploading just automating the archiving.

From what I've read online the path of client side files which are uploaded cannot be seen by the server due to security from the web browser and servers cannot download a file into any directory it chooses other then the download directory determine by the client.

Is there any way around these issues, I’ve heard rumors that it might be possible using JavaScript although I have no experience using JavaScript.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `Is there any way around these issues`, I hope not, there is a very good reason why you can't do that.

Comment: You mean save a file somewhere on the client?

Comment: If I am put to such situation, I would create a windows form application having a web browser in it, so that my win form application can pick up the path and do archiving, where as the uploading will be done via web browser control

Comment: @artm That's right, the client has a folder where they archive these files on the their computer.  The Web app needs to do this automatically.

Comment: @10bit What if this was allowed and you put a hacked sydtem32.dll in windows directory?

Comment: @artm I understand that they prevent it due to security.  To be honest I kinda hope it isn't possible due to malicious acts like that, but at the same time that is what my boss is requesting so I have to look around for options.

Comment: @10bit Not possible fortunately. Tell your boss it can't be done.

Comment: @UsmanWaheed That might be a good idea that I could pitch to my boss.  I've never tried making such a program before but if it can be done it might work for them.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this demo for zip.js project:
http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo1.html

You have in fact three options:

1. zip it on client side using JS and upload to server from memory
2. zip it on client side using things running on client side like Java
   Applet / Flash or Silverlight
3. make click once application which will install from the browser zip
   the files and upload to server (probably too elaborated... for
   simple issue)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will need to figure out how to zip the files client side, then move it, so learning how to zip will be helpful.  The main problem though is moving the archive to a folder on the client side, which seems to be impossible due to security issues.

Comment: This you can only achieve using third approach with click once application but this is huge... for this purpose... or JAVA Applet with full permissions on client side it can also write to any location.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it does seem pretty elaborated just for this purpose but it is a possibility.