# Rename or Delete a File on Client's Machine after Upload

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

Hello I have a couple of questions.

-Is there a way to be able to either delete or rename a file on the **client’s** machine after he uploads the file via a file upload control to the server.

-This one is closer to a question that I asked before ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530930/archiving-file-on-clients-computer)), would you be able to get the path of a uploaded file or move the uploaded file on a **client’s** computer if the client has IE Trusted Sites Security Zone for your website.

The overall problem is that Clients are uploading many files to a website. Once the file is uploaded it needs to be clear on the **client's** computer that the file already has been uploaded once so that they do not miss or re-upload the same file.  If the file has been renamed, moved, or deleted upon upload then it would be difficult for them to miss or re-upload a file.

Comment: `if (!File.Exists(file path here);`?

Comment: @Brian the question is whether a website can change something on the client's computer automatically, which would be a huge security issue.

Comment: @Brian I was thinking something similar, like checking if a upload file is already on the server in order to prevent duplicate files, however that doesn't stop the big issue of missed files.

Comment: I should have been more specific with my question...  That code snippet was meant for server-side **only**.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot delete files from the client's machine (*not without some type of extension or parallel software running on the machine*). I would instead encourage you to consider another route. When multiple files are selected for upload, you have access to their [file names and file sizes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) via JavaScript:

```js
fileupload.addEventListener( "change", function () {
    console.log( this.files ); // FileList {0: File, 1: File, 2: File, length: 3}
});
```

I would suggest you send this list of details over to a server-side script that inspects them against a history of uploads from the current user. If matches exist, you can relay that information back to the user and allow them to modify their list of files to upload.

Comment: // , Nice. I like how this even included a code example! In addition, you might just have the client-side script make a quick name comparison prior to upload. It need not even be server-side.

Comment: @37coins You *could* store a list of recently-uploaded files on the client-side, but that would be more fragile than storing them server-side.

Comment: // , I did not mean to imply storing any data client-side for more than a few seconds for that. It could just send a request for a context-filtered json at the moment of the file being added to the list of files to upload.

Comment: As, I think I see what you're saying. Request a list of recently-uploaded files from the server, and compare the FileList against *that* server response?

Comment: I think it's also possible to compare MD5 hashes of the file binary to completely ensure that there are no doubles, but that might be overkill.

Comment: // , Er, yes, Jonathan, only think slightly more ridiculously over-engineered.